# how to reverse an animation - android

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a test app in android and a TextView displayed on it.
on a left swipe i am 'animating' that TextView off the screen.
I have used the following code for that:

**res/anim/swipoff1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500" >
    </rotate>

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

**and in the activity**

```
Animation swipe_off_1 = 
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.swipoff1);
```

on left swipe :

```
dummy_textview.startAnimation(swipe_off_1);
```

on right swipe :

```
dummy_textview.clearAnimation();
```

**I plan to reverse the animation on right swipe.**

need help to reverse the animation from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) {
        return Math.abs(paramFloat -1f);
    }
}
```

Then on your animation you can set your new interpolator:

```
myAnimation.setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator());
```

Just a template, but should be able to do this for your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
animate().translationX(0);
animate().translationY(0);
```

and so on...